# C# Linq Select from one to many but if in the many one is false dont return

Tags: c#, database, linq

sorry for asking i tried searching for a similar query but no result or i did not know what am looking for so here is the question:

Two tables the User_Table primary key is in Message_Tabel as foreign key Each message has a code and is a isReplyed (true, false)

now how can i retrieve the users whose messages with a certain code and none has been replied

example:

```
UserTabel                            
==========            
ID 1                 
ID 2                
ID 3                 
ID 4                 
ID 5                
ID 6                
ID 7                 
ID 7                 



                Message_Tabel             
           =============================================
            ID 1       Code 22X      Replied False   MID 1
            ID 1       Code 20X      Replied False   MID 2
            ID 1       Code 22X      Replied true    MID 3
            ID 1       Code 22X      Replied False   MID 4
            ID 2       Code 22X      Replied False   MID 5
            ID 3       Code 22X      Replied true    MID 6
            ID 2       Code 22X      Replied False   MID 7
            ID 2       Code 22X      Replied False   MID 8
```

with the query to all users messages with code 22X to be retrieved and none replied:
messages grouped by user id
would retrieve all the messages of User with Id 2 and not ID 1 or 3 cause one is already replied with that code.

I wanted it so if that any user can send as many messages with a certain code but i will reply once to each message with that code and ignore the rest

I hope it all makes sense

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you provide the query you are currently using? Are you using EF or L2S?

Comment: Am a noob using metalSQL then use the .dbml (System.Data.Linq.DataContext) and have not created any code for this type of query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do the trick (untested):

```
        var users = context.Messages
            .Where(m => m.Code == "22X")
            .GroupBy(m => m.User)
            .Where(m => m.All(x => x.Replied == false))
            .Select(p => p.Key);
```

That should return the users that meet your expectation. If you want you can alter the query to return the messages as well, so that you can pick which one to reply to.